# PHP files for website show error: can not find driver

Tags: php, sql, pdo, driver

I am creating a blog for my portfolio website and I am developing it from scratch. I have connected my database and the connection is there but it's saying it can't find the driver.

I have been reading for hours through all the other posts and none of the answers have solved my problem. I have downloaded actual files that said they were drivers, I have taken the semi colons out of the php.ini file, I have messed with my code over and over to check for spelling errors, and I have checked to make sure all the drivers are actually loaded and working on my PHPinfo page.

I feel like I'm forgetting a key piece of information to help get this question answered but nothings coming to mind. I'll update if I think of anything else. Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "portfolio_blog.sql";
global $db;


function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password){
    $db = new PDO('mysqli:host=$hostname;$dbname', $username, $password);
    return $db;
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}

try {
    $db = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password);
    echo 'Connected to database';
}

    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I don't have high enough confidence to post this as an answer but: what happens if you change `mysqli` to `mysql` in your dsn? (`'mysql:host=$hostname;$dbname'`)

Comment: Also, it'd be very helpful if you copy/pasted the exact error you're getting from PHP.

Comment: Literally all it says is "could not find driver" on a giant white screen. I'll give your suggestion a go.

Comment: I made the change, just taking out the 'i' and this is the error it threw: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known."

Comment: Should it be `new PDO("mysqli:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);` ? You need to use double quote so that PHP can validate the variable inside the string

Comment: I just tried that and it stills says it can't find the driver.

Comment: [How to connect with PDO properly](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql). A complete guide

Comment: @YourCommonSense: I copied and pasted and tweaked exactly what that article said to write and it WORKED. I have been looking all over at so many articles and I never came across that one. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a few issues:

1. The driver issue.

The driver is called `mysql`, you've input `mysqli`. `mysqli` is an extension for PHP that replaced the older, obsolete, `mysql` extension. Neither of which have anything to do with PDO unfortunately.

The driver you're looking for is `mysql`. The first change is to change `'mysqli:host=$hostname;$dbname'` to `'mysql:host=$hostname;$dbname'`.

2. `'` vs. `''`

You're using a single quote, but it looks like you're trying to use the value of `$hostname` and `$dbname` in your dsn string. If you want to use those variables, you'll need to use double quotes for PHP to perform the replacement. Using single quotes will *litterally* put `$hostname` and `$dbname` into the argument.

Second change is going from `'mysql:host=$hostname;$dbname'` to `"mysql:host=$hostname;$dbname"`

3. `$dbname` isn't defined.

You'll need to make it in scope.

```
function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname){
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;$dbname", $username, $password);
    return $db;
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
```

4. The DSN is looking for the database name. Not a SQL file.

`$dbname` is `"portfolio_blog.sql"` suggesting that you're trying to load a `.sql` file. You'll need to provide the name of the database instead. I don't know what that is so you'll probably need to put it in yourself.

I think you'll need to change your DSN to handle this again.

Example, assuming the database name is `portfolio_blog`:

`$dbname = "portfolio_blog"`

and

`"mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname"`

---

I'd recomend something like this:

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//database credentials
$hostname = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "portfolio_blog";
global $db;


function testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname){
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    return $db;
}

try {
    $db = testdb_connect ($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
    echo 'Connected to database';
}

    catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

There's a fair chance I missed something, you'll have to take the error messages as they come.

Good luck.

Comment: Good aim but you've got a few issues as well: return $db; before  $db->setAttribute. global $db makes no sense in the global scope. echo $e->getMessage(); is not [how errors are reported in XXI century](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting).

Comment: I appreciate your time!!! I got this error figured out but heaven knows I have a lot more to tackle. Thank you for helping me!